# When to use {} () in constructors

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, sfml

In `Game.h`, I have a class named `Game`:

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    void run();
private:
    sf::Event e;
    sf::RenderWindow app;
    sf::Clock delay;
    unsigned counter = 0;
    Ice *ball = new Ice(app);
    Players *players = new Players(app);
    Collision collision;
    void handleEvent();
};
```

Then, in `Game.cpp`, I use:

```
Game::Game() : app({1000,800},"NAME")
{
}
```

The syntax

```
Game::Game() : app(sf::VideoMode(1000,800),"NAME")
{
}
```

also works.

My question is: why can I omit `sf::VideoMode` in the first case, and if I do so, why do I *HAVE* to use `{}` for the videomode parameters? Using `()` in the first case results in an error.

Comment: Can you post your variables of Game class?

Comment: `()` should not be used for initialization at all. See [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Comment: Warning: With `Ice *ball = new Ice(app);` and `Players *players = new Players(app);` `Game` no longer observes the Rule of Three. This can lead to some nasty errors and ugly debugging. I recommend familiarizing yourself with [the Rules of 3, 5, and 0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and NOT using dynamic allocation here. You can initialize `ball` and `players` as plain old member variables in the Member Initializer List the same as you do with `app`.

Comment: @user4581301 Could you explain me with an example why not following this rules can lead to errors?

Comment: There are many ways you can accidentally copy or assign a class, common cases are stuffing it into a standard container, [as in this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48530665/4581301), and passing it by value. The default behaviour results in two objects pointing to the same storage. Sooner or later one of the copies is destroyed and releases the pointer, and this leaves the other copy pointing to invalid memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Game` constructor is calling the following [`sf::RenderWindow`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php) constructor:

```
RenderWindow (VideoMode mode, const String &title, Uint32 style=Style::Default, const ContextSettings &settings=ContextSettings())
```

You have to pass it a fully constructed [`sf::VideoMode`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1VideoMode.php) object.

Both of your examples are constructing a temporary `VideoMode` object inline in the `sf::RenderWindow` constructor call.  They are both calling the following `sf::VideoMode` constructor, just using different syntaxes:

```
VideoMode (unsigned int modeWidth, unsigned int modeHeight, unsigned int modeBitsPerPixel=32)
```

C++11 introduced a new feature called "Uniform Initialization", which unifies various different types of initialization syntaxes used in different contexts into a single syntax using curly braces, thus greatly simplifying coding.  In this case, [List Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) is being used to initialize a temporary object using a `braced-init-list`. It is this feature that allows your `{1000,800}` example to construct a temporary `sf::VideoMode` object directly in a function parameter without having to explicitly state its class name.

Earlier C++ versions do not have "Uniform Initialization".  In those versions, constructors can only be called explicitly by name.  That is what allows your `sf::VideoMode(1000,800)` example to construct a temporary `sf::VideoMode` object (and it is still valid syntax in C++11 and later, too).

`(1000,800)` by itself is not valid C++ syntax for constructing an object, in any C++ version.

Answer (score 2):

> why can I omit `sf::VideoMode` in the first case

Because `app`'s constructor's first parameter is declared as having type `sf::VideoMode` already.

It's the same reason you can write `long v = 1;` instead of having to write `long v = long{1};` or something like that: the compiler knows the type of the variable or parameter being initialised, and can check that that type supports construction using the initialiser you specified, even if the initialiser doesn't have the same type.

> and if I do so, why do I HAVE to use `{}` for the videomode parameters?

Because `(1000,800)` already had a different much older meaning: it means "get the value `1000`, discard that, then get the value `800` instead". Admittedly that'd be pointless in this case, but there's no way of rewriting the language in such a way that `(1000,800)` works in your case while simultaneously sensible previously valid code continues to work too.