# C++ trouble with deallocating memory taken by vector elements

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

So the problem is that when i try to push non-dynamic obj to playerList or when I try to delete n I get segfault (core dump). I assume that the problem is caused when Helper class is being destroyed so the vector also is being destroyed so it tries to destroy object in itself which does not exist anymore. However when i use playerList.clear() the problem still exist. I think i could just destroy objects in playerList() with ~Helper(). But I would like to know why i cannot use non-dynamic objects and just clear them out of playerList at the end of Run().

```
class Helper{
public:

    void Run();


private:
    std::vector<Player>playerList;
    ...
};
```

that's how Run() looks like:

```
using namespace std;

void Helper::Run(){
    Player *n = new Player();
    playerList.push_back(*n); //Yup. There is a memleak
}
```

also 
Player.h:

```
class Player{
public:

    ...
    ~Player();

private:
    ...
    IClass* typeOfClass = new Warrior();
};
```

and ~Player:

```
Player::~Player(){
    delete typeOfClass;
}
```

and Warrior (has no effect on the problem)

```
class Warrior {
public:

    int GetMeleeAttack();
    int GetRangedAttack();
    int GetMagicAttack();
    int AgilityAction();
    int StrengthAction();
    int IntelligenceAction();
    void WhoAmI();

private:

};
```

Warrior's methods just returns some integers.

Comment: The `Run` method looks really weird. It has a memory leak. Why allocate any new memory at all? What is Warrior? please make a [mcve]

Comment: use std::shared_ptr

Comment: Unrelated: In addition to deleting the assignment operator, you should also delete the copy constructor.

Comment: I have described that it has mem leak because i could not use delete n. It caused segfault.

Comment: Stop using raw pointers, then all of these problems go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<Player>playerList;
```

should be

```
std::vector<Player*>playerList;
```

if you want to allocate them dynamically. The other method would be to emplace each element and not use new.

When using new you are allocating on the heap but you are creating a new element in the vector by passing the value from the one allocated on heap. And you have a dangling pointer ( memory leak )

Remember to deallocate all the elements at the destruction of the vector if you are using a vector of pointers.

Another method would be:

```
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Player> >playerList;
```

That will take care of the allocation issue.

Comment: `std::vector<Player*>playerList` worked properly with deallocation. However when I try `Player n = Player()` and `playerList.emplace_back(n)` it still causes the error.

Comment: You can use `playerList.emplace_back();` directly, you don't need to create another object.

Comment: @user4581301 I know the smart pointers however in this case i had a problem with vector and it's logic.

Comment: @VictorPadureanu oh that's how it works. Thanks a lot! However is there a possibility to pass non-dynamic objects to the vector? !Edit Nevermind. I can still pass arguments through emplace.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you need to write a copy constructor for the class you want to use. Also you need to delete the allocated object. Player n = Player(); playerList.push_back(n); / Player* n = new Player(); playerList.push_back(*n); delete n;

Comment: @VictorPadureanu. Okay. I think i have to read vector documentation deeply. Thank you very much!

Comment: @J.Cierpich Handy reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three. TL;DR, if you need to delete something in the destructor, odds are really good you need to copy and assign it correctly as well.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::vector`s main job is to dynamically allocate objects for you, so you don't need to use `new` and `delete`.

```
void Helper::Run(){
    playerList.push_back(Player());
}
```

This will default-construct a new player object and add it to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Yes, the problem can be solved by storing pointers to `Player`, but this needlessly adds to the problems caused by having to store a pointer to `IClass` inside `Player`.

Instead you can make the whole problem go away by making

```
IClass* typeOfClass;
```

into

```
std::unique_ptr<IClass> typeOfClass;
```

or

```
std::shared_ptr<IClass> typeOfClass;
```

and using

```
playerList.emplace_back();
```

in `Helper::Run`.

## TL;DR

`std::vector` does a lot of copying and destroying of copies. In order to do this, objects contained by a `vector` must comply with one of the [Rules of Three, Five, or Zero.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Because `Player` owns a pointer and uses the default copy functions the rule of 3/5/0 requirement is not observed. As a result, a copy's `typeOfClass` points to the same place as the source's `typeOfClass`. When either the source or the copy is destroyed, it deletes the `typeOfClass` that both source and copy are using, leaving the other pointing at invalid memory. The program is now broken and may or may not crash.

But if `Player` observes the Rules and has a move constructor and a move assignment operator like below

```
class Player{
public:

    ...
    ~Player();
    Player(Player && src)
    {
        typeOfClass = src.typeOfClass;
        src.typeOfClass = nullptr;
    }
    Player& operator=(Player && src)
    {
        typeOfClass = src.typeOfClass;
        src.typeOfClass = nullptr;
    }
private:
    ...
    IClass* typeOfClass = new Warrior();
};
```

Then `vector` can move `Players` around without having two `Player`s sharing the same data and `Helper::Run` can look like

```
void Helper::Run(){
    playerList.emplace_back();
}
```

There will be no memory leaks and fewer pointers in play.

However... What you really want is to do as little special handling as possible. Every special case means more testing. If you can protect `typeOfClass` right at its source, then `Player` can be dumb as a post and adhere to the Rule of Zero.

In this case that means using a proxy object like a smart pointer to take ownership of `typeOfClass` and manage its lifespan for you. If all Warriors can have the same `Warrior` instance, that means `std:shared_ptr`. If Warriors need separate `Warrior` instances to handle bookkeeping for the containing `Player` instance you want a `unique_ptr`.